# Grounding an Opto-isolated Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

[image]

First off - thank you all so much for all you have done for me, and the hobbyists all around the world.  I love you all and truly appreciate what you do for the field of hobby-ism.

The AC in this circuit is the mains from the wall, 120v AC.  The full wave rectified voltage is 170v DC. My goal was to control the vacuum motor speed using python in the Raspberry Pi.
I am presently running the above setup, and it seems to work fine for the most part.

I am trying to find a better solution for grounding so that I can attempt to solve two minor issues: (and make it safer?)

**ISSUE ONE:** I have a k type thermocouple also attached to pins on the Raspberry Pi.  It works perfectly, up to the second the motor starts up.  Then, the temperature reading goes crazy, jumping all over the place.  I suspect due to noise.  I have read that one should ground the thermocouple's breakout board to "MECHANICAL GROUND".  Which, as I understand it, is not presently in my circuit.

**ISSUE TWO:** The motor runs slightly more erratically when I have the thermocouple active.  I say "erratic" because I can hear it rise and fall slightly every 30 seconds or so.  This does not happen when I remove the thermocouple from the circuit.

**Thus my questions are:**

1)  Are chassis ground, mechanical ground, and earth ground the same thing when it boils down to it?  Which one should I connect my thermocouple to? What if I ground my circuit like the schematic I created below, and then tie my thermocouple ground into earth ground.  In doing that, wouldn't I just basically be destroying the electrical isolation that I created with the optoisolator?  I would hate to fry another Raspberry Pi, that was so sad.

2)  Is there any advantage to grounding the negative side of my capacitor to earth ground?  I am thinking that it must be, at the very least, a bit safer.

3)  Is earth ground just the third prong on a normal household outlet?

Proposed circuit modification:
[image]

-The Raspberry Pi is powered by a 5v wall wort.

-The Thermocouple is connected using the MAX31855 breakout board, and is interfaced as such, using a soldered PCB and a ribbon cable to the Pi:
[image]

[image]

This is what it looks like in real life, the yellow wire is a grounding wire that I added to see if grounding to a different ground pin on the Pi would make a difference in my wildly fluctuating temperature data.  It sadly did not:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit diagram does not show how your PWM generator (Raspberry Pi in your case) is powered. I will guess here that it is a separate power supply based on an isolated transformer, like a wall wart (ubiquitous little black plugin boxes that waste energy 24/7 when people leave them plugged in). You also do not show the thermocouple connection, which would be helpful. Interfacing a thermocouple to such is apparently non-trivial:

http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/blog/2014/11/14/temperature-measurement-for-lab-and-science-projects

So my best guess/speculation (until further details are provided) is that the thermocouple is picking up noise from the motor and messing with the Raspberry Pi.

The first solution I would try would be to electrically isolate the temperature measurement function from the Raspberry Pi, or use a measurement method that does not involve dangling long wires. I have temperature measurement ICs in my junk box, maybe you do, too.

Comment: Thank you user901750!  I very much appreciate the help.  I have updated my question with a few more pictures and information that I neglected to include the first time around.  Also, I have learned that one should never add earth ground to a full wave rectifier.  It tripped my 5 amp fuse on the transformer.  Thank you again!

Comment: Your additional details are helpful. I googled MAX31855 and found that (just as I suspected) it does not provide isolation between the thermocouple and the MAX IC, which is not isolated from the Raspberry Pi. So I again suggest that the long dangling thermocouple wires near the EMI-emitting (sparking?) electric motor are causing malfunction in the Raspberry Pi. Isolated temperature sensing is possible (google it). You can also try wrapping tape around the thermocouple junction and inserting the whole assembly inside a copper tube that is connected to GND on the Raspberry Pi.